# A set with constraints

Tags: combinatorics

Let $X$ be a finite collection of natural numbers. ($X$ is a multiset.)
Define $R$ as the set of all $(A,B)$ such that $X$ is disjoint union of non-empty sets $A$ and $B$.
Let $S$ be the set of elements $(A,B)$ of $R$ in such a way that $\Sigma_{a\in A} a$ is minimum among all elements of $R$.

What is the lower bound for $(A,B)\in S$ in terms of the minimum of $X$?

Comment: Not sure this is clear.  Isn't that sum minimized by taking $A=\{a_0\}$ where $a_0$ is the least natural number in $X$?

Comment: @lulu The problem here is that $X$ is a multiset. Maybe there 5 $a_0$ in $X$.

Comment: Ok, you did say that $A,B$ were disjoint.  In any case, $A$ consists of all copies of a single number in $X$, so just go case by case.  It is true, however, that this way there might be more than one $A$ that works.